# How to set each type of page transition to a specific page? (css animations)

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

So I have 4 different room transitions (up, down, left & right). I want to be able to set each transition to go to a specific page, and repeat if the same transition is clicked again.

For example, have "left" (data-animation 55) goto "Page1.html", and if I was already on "Page1.html", then it would just transition right back into the page. And I would have the "right" button, go to "Page2.html", etc.

https://github.com/cweigen/page_transition_room

There's the github repo, but this is the code that I've been messing with, experimenting with different versions of it to attempt going to a specific page and repeating if the same button is clicked, but go to another specific page is another menu button is clicked.

```
            <div class="pt-triggers">
  <div id="dl-menu" >

            <ul class="dl-menu">
            <li data-animation="54"><a href="#" > right </a></li>
            <div class="pt-triggers1">
            <li data-animation="55"><a href="#" > left</a></li>
            <div class="pt-triggers2">
            <li data-animation="56"><a href="#" > down</a></li>
            <div class="pt-triggers3">
            <li data-animation="57"><a href="#" > up</a></li></div>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
```

```
    <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
        <div class="pt-page pt-page-1"><iframe src="http://visiondigit.al/VisionDigital_Launch/" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe></div>
        <div class="pt-page pt-page-2"><iframe src="http://scsuchat.com" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe></div>


       </div>
```

Comment: Didn't quite get you. Did you mean if you are already on the left page, clicking left will just transition the current page again and stays there?

Comment: That is what I meant, but I'm actually going to remove the link once on that page. So once you're on "leftpage", the left button will be removed, but reappear once you're back on any other page.

Comment: make a working fiddle and I can have a look for you.

Comment: https://github.com/cweigen/page_transition_room

Comment: I couldn't get a fiddle working properly for you to see what I mean.

If you download that github repo, then make your browser full screen, (i didn't properly place the different buttons, as I was testing). Once you see the left, right, down, up, buttons then upon clicking you'll see the effect I'm going for.

However....I want for 'transitionUp' to goto 'page1.html'. I'm unsure how to specify which transition goes to which page and no others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using is not the best choice for your task. However, it does provide as many as 67 different transition effects, which are defined in `**pagetransions.js**` and called using **`data-animation`** attribute. Have a look at the js file and you can choose the specific animation you are looking for.

To solve your other problem, you'll have to write a bit of your own code as the author doesn't provide a function to link each button with specific page, nor hiding the button when you are already on that page. You can use jQuery to do so.

But like I said, this is not the best nor the only option you have.
Check

> **[THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/7hvjJ/)**

I have created a structure that mostly mimics your requirements. Have a play and try to understand the demo. The structure is quite simple. It uses two external resources which you can see and download from the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked over the original code before and I do understand where the animations are located and that they're defined by data-animation. Sorry about asking others to do it. I'll play with this code, I really appreciate the help.